# Auto trigger event from firebase backend to Android frontend

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so my situation is that I have a firebase real time database set up for my app backend. Generally speaking, the db stores request nodes, and each request has an 'Expiration' date/time.

I desire functionality when the expiration time for a request occurs, an event is triggered which invalidates that request entry in database and also makes it known to the app frontend where I can show a message to user when he opens the app.

Can you suggest how should I go about this?I'm kinda stuck on this as I'm fairly new to firebase (and app development) so any help in simpler terms would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in a very simple way using [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

> Cloud Functions for Firebase lets you automatically run backend code in response to events triggered by Firebase features and HTTPS requests. Your code is stored in Google's cloud and runs in a managed environment. There's no need to manage and scale your own servers.

Hoe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is not possible with GCF at this point.

I had a similar question: [Google Cloud Functions: edit Firebase node at a specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718441/google-cloud-functions-edit-firebase-node-at-a-specific-time)