# Google Cloud Functions: edit Firebase node at a specific time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

So the area of interest in my Firebase database is as follows:

```
root  
  -requests  
     - <Autogenerated push() id>  
          - requestValid:  
          - requestExpiry  
                -epochSecond:  
                -nano:
```

requestValid is 0/1. requestExpiry is stored with Java Instant. The requestExpiry is some hours ahead in future. Now I'd like to set requestValid to 0 when the requestExpiry time occurs.

Someone suggested me that Google Cloud Functions could help me with that. But I can't see how? How would my function keep waiting and auto-fire once requestExpiry has passed? It'll be very helpful if you could show the right approach using GCF, or any easier alternative you can suggest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no way to keep a function waiting for an arbitrarily long amount of time.  Functions will be terminated after their configured timeout (9 minutes max).  Also, there is currently no way to schedule the execution of a function after some delay.  You'd need to write something using some other backend component to "long poll" the value for a change and react as needed.

It's a common request to have some sort of built-in scheduling mechanism for functions, and the Cloud Functions team is looking into that.